Double Response Issue with JWT Authentication in ASP.NET Core
I'm facing an issue with my JWT authentication in ASP.NET Core where I'm getting duplicate responses.
Here's the relevant code for the JWT authentication:
public static class JwtAuthExtension
{
    public static void AddGatewayCustomJwtAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        AuthDbConfigurations _authConfiguration = AuthDbConfigurations.Instance;
        _authConfiguration.Initialize();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("F-JaNdRfUserjd89#5*6Xn2r5usErw8x/A?D(G+KbPeShV")),
                ValidIssuer = "SecureIssuer",
                ValidAudience = "SecureIssuerClient"
            };
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = ctx =>
                {
                    var actionName = ctx.Request.RouteValues["action"]?.ToString() ?? String.Empty;

                    if (ctx.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey(CommonConstants.TokenName) &&
                    !actionName.Equals("Authenticate", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                    !actionName.Equals("RenewToken", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        ctx.Token = ctx.Request.Cookies[CommonConstants.TokenName];
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnAuthenticationFailed = ctx =>
                {
                    if (!ctx.Response.HasStarted)
                    {
                        if (ctx.Exception is SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException || ctx.Exception is SecurityTokenMalformedException)
                        {
                            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("X-TOKEN-TAMPERED", "true");
                            ctx.Response.StatusCode = 498;
                            ctx.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                            var tamperedPayload = new TokenTamperedResponse();
                            var tamperedMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tamperedPayload);
                            return ctx.Response.WriteAsync(tamperedMessage);
                        }
                        else if (ctx.Exception is SecurityTokenExpiredException)
                        {
                            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("IS-TOKEN-EXPIRED", "true");
                            ctx.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                            ctx.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                            var payload = new UnAuthorizedResponse("Token Expired");
                            var errorMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
                            return ctx.Response.WriteAsync(errorMessage);
                        }
                    }

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnChallenge = ctx =>
                {
                    if (!ctx.Response.HasStarted)
                    {
                        ctx.HandleResponse();

                        if (ctx.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("X-TOKEN-TAMPERED"))
                        {
                            ctx.Response.StatusCode = 498;
                            ctx.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                            var tamperedPayload = new TokenTamperedResponse();
                            var tamperedMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tamperedPayload);
                            return ctx.Response.WriteAsync(tamperedMessage);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ctx.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                            ctx.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                            var payload = new UnAuthorizedResponse();
                            var errorMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
                            return ctx.Response.WriteAsync(errorMessage);
                        }
                    }

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
                {
                    await Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
    }
}


I have tried various things like checking whether the response has started or not by putting the code in if condition and while debugging the code I found that it is going to my RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware which is registered in my Gateway class library project. Below is the code of RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware
public class RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware> _logger;
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Request.EnableBuffering();

        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        var request = await FormatRequest(context.Request);

        builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        builder.Append("Request: ").AppendLine(request);
        builder.AppendLine("Request headers:");
        foreach (var header in context.Request.Headers)
        {
            builder.Append(header.Key).Append(':').AppendLine(header.Value);
        }

        //Copy a pointer to the original response body stream
        var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

        //Create a new memory stream...
        using var responseBody = new MemoryStream();
        //...and use that for the temporary response body
        context.Response.Body = responseBody;

        //Continue down the Middleware pipeline, eventually returning to this class
        await _next(context);

        //Format the response from the server
        var response = await FormatResponse(context.Response);
        builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        builder.Append("Response: ").AppendLine(response);
        builder.AppendLine("Response headers: ");
        foreach (var header in context.Response.Headers)
        {
            builder.Append(header.Key).Append(':').AppendLine(header.Value);
        }

        //Save log to chosen datastore
        _logger.LogInformation(builder.ToString());

        //Copy the contents of the new memory stream (which contains the response) to the original stream, which is then returned to the client.
        await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
    }

    private static async Task<string> FormatRequest(HttpRequest request)
    {
        // Leave the body open so the next middleware can read it.
        using var reader = new StreamReader(
            request.Body,
            encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
            detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false,
            leaveOpen: true);
        var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        // Do some processing with body…

        var formattedRequest = $"{request.Scheme} {request.Host}{request.Path} {request.QueryString} {body}";

        // Reset the request body stream position so the next middleware can read it
        request.Body.Position = 0;

        return formattedRequest;
    }

    private async Task<string> FormatResponse(HttpResponse response)
    {
        //We need to read the response stream from the beginning...
        response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        //...and copy it into a string
        string text = await new StreamReader(response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

        //We need to reset the reader for the response so that the client can read it.
        response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        //Return the string for the response, including the status code (e.g. 200, 404, 401, etc.)
        return $"{response.StatusCode}: {text}";
    }
}

After tampering the token value I am expecting that after that if any HTTP request will be made it will return my TokenTampered response but instead I was getting two appended response which I had shown below
API Response after token tampering

{
"StatusCode": 498,
"Succeeded": false,
"Message": "Token Tampered"
}{
"StatusCode": 498,
"Succeeded": false,
"Message": "Token Tampered"
}

which is expected to come with only a single response.

I think the issue belongs to the custom JWT authentication events and the RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware. Make sure the response handling in the JWT events does not write the response multiple times and that the logging middleware correctly handles the response stream without causing duplication, in that case, check the loggin. Additionally, verifying the order of middleware registration in the program.cs class is crucial to ensure that the logging middleware and authentication middleware are properly ordered.

I encountered the exact same problem recently. I leave a working code example below. Steps you should pay attention to while reading response body;
1- You should assign the original body into a variable
var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

2- After reading the body, you should set the position of the stream position you used to read the body to 0 and copy it to the original body stream.
emptyResponseBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
await emptyResponseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);

3- You must assign the original body that you assigned to the variable in step 1 back to the response body.
 context.Response.Body = originalBodyStream;

When you perform these 3 steps, you will perform the same operation as context.Request.EnableBuffering(); or context.Request.EnableRewind(); operations.
You've already done steps 1 and 2. I think the problem will be solved if you add the assignment process in step 3 to the end of the middleware.
I am sharing my own working code block to help you.
PS: Using RecyclableMemoryStreamManager may provide performance benefits in such operations.
Also, as @Md Farid Uddin Kiron mentioned in the comment, you should make sure that the middleware order is correct. My RequestResponseMiddleware is at the top of the request pipeline.

Here is my RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware.cs;

    using Microsoft.IO;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    
    namespace MyApp.Api.Middlewares;
    

    public class RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next = next;
        private readonly ILogger _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware>();
        private readonly RecyclableMemoryStreamManager _recyclableMemoryStreamManager = new();
        private readonly Stopwatch _sw = new();
        private readonly RequestInfo _requestInfo = new();
    
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            var activity = new Activity("LoggingActivity");
    
            activity.Start();
    
            _sw.Restart();
    
            await ReadRequestAsync(context);
            await LogResponseAsync(context);
    
            activity.Dispose();
        }
    
        private async Task ReadRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();
    
            await using var requestStream = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream();
    
            await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(requestStream);
    
            _requestInfo.Method = context.Request.Method;
    
            _requestInfo.Body = await ReadStreamInChunksAsync(requestStream);
    
            _requestInfo.Headers = context.Request.Headers;
    
            _requestInfo.ContentLength = context.Request.ContentLength ?? 0;
    
            _requestInfo.AbsoluteUri = string.Concat(context.Request.Scheme,
                                                     "://",
                                                     context.Request.Host.ToUriComponent(),
                                                     context.Request.PathBase.ToUriComponent(),
                                                     context.Request.Path.ToUriComponent(),
                                                     context.Request.QueryString.ToUriComponent());
    
            _requestInfo.QueryString = context.Request.QueryString.ToUriComponent();
    
            context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        }
    
        private async Task LogResponseAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;
    
            try
            {
                await using var emptyResponseBody = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream();
    
                context.Response.Body = emptyResponseBody;
    
                await _next(context);
    
                emptyResponseBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    
                using var streamReader = new StreamReader(emptyResponseBody);
    
                var responseBody = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    
                if (!IsUIReqeust(context))
                    responseBody = Regex.Unescape(responseBody);
    
                emptyResponseBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      
                _sw.Stop();
    
                _logger.LogInformation("your-log");
    
                await emptyResponseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
            }
            finally
            {
                context.Response.Body = originalBodyStream;
            }
        }
    
        private static async Task<string> ReadStreamInChunksAsync(RecyclableMemoryStream stream)
        {
            const int readChunkBufferLength = 4096;
    
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    
            using var textWriter = new StringWriter();
    
            using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    
            var readChunk = new char[readChunkBufferLength];
    
            int readChunkLength;
    
            do
            {
                readChunkLength = await reader.ReadBlockAsync(readChunk, 0, readChunkBufferLength);
    
                await textWriter.WriteAsync(readChunk, 0, readChunkLength);
    
            } while (readChunkLength > 0);
    
            return Regex.Unescape(textWriter.ToString());
        }
    
        private static bool IsUIReqeust(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api/documentation")
                || httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api/hc")
                || httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api/health-check")
                || httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api/hc-ui"))
                return true;
    
            return false;
        }
    }


Here's the relevant code for the JWT authentication:

    services.AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {    
             // This event is fired when the token is not provided or after OnForbidden and OnAuthenticationFailed events fired.
             OnChallenge = async context =>
             {
                  // We will add this check and response rewrite when the token is not provided.
                  // At the same time, since I set the response code in the OnForbidden and OnAuthenticationFailed events, it was added in order not to rewrite the response a second time.
                  if (!(context.Response.StatusCode == 403 || context.Response.StatusCode == 401))
                  {
                        // Since this scenario will work when a token is not sent to an endpoint that requires authorization, I set the response to 401.
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        await WriteResponseAsync(context, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                  }
             },
             OnForbidden = async context =>
             {
                  // Invalid permissions
                  context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                  await WriteResponseAsync(context, HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
             },
             OnAuthenticationFailed = async context =>
             {
                  // Invalid token
                  context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                  await WriteResponseAsync(context, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
             },
        };
    
        static Task WriteResponseAsync(BaseContext<JwtBearerOptions> context, HttpStatusCode statusCode)
        {
            if (!(context.Response.StatusCode is >= 200 and <= 299))
                context.Response.OnStarting(async () =>
                {              
                    if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
                    {                        
                        context.Response.ContentType = MimeTypeNames.ApplicationJson;
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)statusCode;
    
                        await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(your-response-model);
                    }
                });
    
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    });



EDIT;
I detected the problem by reproducing your code. The problem arises from the use of JWT events.

OnChallenge: This event is triggered when an authentication challenge occurs, such as when a 401 Unauthorized response is about to be sent.
OnForbidden: This event is triggered when a 403 Forbidden response is about to be sent.
OnAuthenticationFailed: This event is triggered if the authentication process fails.

So, in your code, the response is first rewritten in OnAuthenticationFailed and then in OnChallenge. Since you did not write the response body stream from the beginning, it adds it to the end and thus your response becomes a duplicate.
There is a working example in my answer with the response without duplicate. You can use events correctly by establishing your own logic according to your own needs. I only left an example because you can do this in many different ways (You can even solve this by putting a flag in HttpContext.Items indicating whether the response has been rewritten within the event).
PS: I am not deleting the parts about rewriting response.body from my answer because it might be useful for others.

Hy @bugrakosen as I have done the changes in my code not from your code or maybe it had provided me some sort of thought that I managed to get there so I can't validate your answer, but still I accept it and take your word for it. Someone else may find this useful.

Below is the controller code part
public async ValueTask<ResponseBase> LogAsync(ErrorLogDto errorLogsDto)
{
    try
    {
        if (errorLogsDto == null)
            return new BadRequestResponse();

    var logConfigResponse = await _logConfigService.GetAsync(UserInfo.GetClientUkey());
    if (logConfigResponse.Succeeded)
        isLog = ((SuccessDataResponse<LogConfigDto>)logConfigResponse).Data.IsErrorLog;

    if(!isLog)
        return new SuccessResponse();

    var logService = _logService(XrmLogEvents.ErrorLog);
    var commonInfoDto = HttpContextService.GetHttpContextLogInfo();

    await _errorLogService.LogAsync(errorLogsDto, commonInfoDto);
    return new SuccessResponse();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return new InternalServerErrorResponse(ex.Message,ex);
}

}
Below is the GetAsync method called above
    public async ValueTask<ResponseBase> GetAsync(string clientUkey)
{
    try
    {
        LogConfigDto dto = _memoryCache.Get($"{CommonConstant.LogConfigCacheKey}{clientUkey}{_environmentName}") as LogConfigDto;
        if (dto != null)
            return new SuccessDataResponse<LogConfigDto>(data: dto);

        var model = await _logConfigRepository.GetSingleAsync(x => x.ClientUkey == clientUkey && x.Environment == _environmentName);
        if (model == null)
            return new NotFoundResponse();

        dto = _mapper.Map<LogConfigDto>(model);
        _memoryCache.Set($"{CommonConstant.LogConfigCacheKey}{clientUkey}{_environmentName}", dto);

        return new SuccessDataResponse<LogConfigDto>(data: dto);
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
    {
        return new InternalServerErrorResponse(ex: ex);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        return new InternalServerErrorResponse(ex: ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new InternalServerErrorResponse(ex: ex);
    }
}

below is the main LogAsync method
    public async ValueTask LogAsync(CustomException exception, HttpContextDto commonInfoDto = null, string errorCode = null)
{
    try
    {

        commonInfoDto ??= HttpContextService.GetHttpContextLogInfo();
        errorCode ??= Convert.ToString(exception.HResult);

        var model = _mapper.Map<ErrorLog>(commonInfoDto);

        model.StackTrace = exception.InnerException == null ? exception.StackTrace : exception.InnerException.StackTrace;
        model.Severity = exception.LogSeverity.ToString();
        model.ErrorCode = errorCode;
        model.ErrorMessage = exception.Message;
        model.IsAlertSent = SendEmailNotification;

        //Add Log Type
        model.LogType = ErrorLogType.Api.ToString();

        StackTrace trace = exception.InnerException == null ? new(exception, true) : new(exception.InnerException, true);
        var frames = trace.GetFrames().FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetFileLineNumber() > 0);
        if(frames != null)
        {
            model.ClassName = GetClassName(frames.GetMethod());
            model.MethodName = GetMethodName(frames.GetMethod());
            model.LineNo = frames.GetFileLineNumber();
        }
        
        model.LoggedOn = DateService.GetCurrentDateTime;
        model.Environment = _environmentName;
        await _errorLogRepository.LogErrorAsync(model);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _ = new InternalServerErrorResponse(ex.Message, ex);
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}


Hy @gurkan I am the owner of the question and the answer I just wanted the show the code which I have tried which obviously can't fit inside the feedback so have to posted that as an answer. Sorry if it doesn't fall under guidelines.

Sure @gurkan thanks for you concern.

@DeepakVerma I edited my answer. We focused on the wrong place :) If you need help, you can leave a comment below my answer.

Hy @bugrakosen After doing some changements as u said I am getting the single response but still there is one API (Error Log) which is returning the appended reponse. I have edited my code written as answer and added the error log code in it.

I think we have solved the problem in your original question. The code blocks you shared in your answer contain methods that we cannot see inside. That's why I could not fully understand the current problem. From here on, I recommend you to ask another question that describes the new problem. If it is a solution to your original question, I will ask you to mark my answer as accepted answer. @DeepakVerma
